# $_GET URL Query to fill elements value without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to see if it possible to post and send information to the url and receive that information in the form of a $_GET request.

This is the link that will be clicked // **Note that admin.php is the current page**

`<a href="admin.php?action=update&id='1'"> Update </a>`

Once this linked is pressed,

```
$updateQuery = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT * FROM `PRODUCT` WHERE `p_id`={$_GET['id']}");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($updateQuery)) {
    $p_name = $row['p_name'];
};
```

And receive the information to be automatically entered within this input box

```
<input type="text" class="ipbtn" value="<?php echo $p_name; ?>" placeholder="Name" name="p_name"/>
```

Now I am aware that this could possibly be done through the usage of Ajax, but on the other hand, I am not sure that changing the url is possible in such a way without refreshing the page. Thank you in advance for any possible suggestions.

Comment: Doing that request and entering the data inside the document without reloading is exactly what ajax does. Just fire the request to your PHP server using javascript, save the response in javascript and modify the DOM (also in javascript)

Comment: I would not take input from the $_GET and insert it directly into your sql like that though, for risk of sql injection.  Doing that you run the risk of having a really bad time.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible to change the url without reloading the page. but... should you?

Comment: Side note, if the results should only have one result, it's strange that you are doing a while look on the sql results.

Comment: The one result is an example. I didn't want to spam the post with 10 different queries at once. It is much tidier with one for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `PHP` in a **SEPARATE FILE** and use `jQuery` `.post()` to access it.  This is the only way to "stay" on the same URL, without "refreshing"   And `.ajax()` is just shorthand for `.post()` -- They are interchangeable with slightly different syntax:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**admin.php**

```
<a onClick="goAdmin();"> Update </a>

<script>

function goAdmin(){
var action = 'update'  // However these will be set
var id = 1             // This is just to show you how to pass them

$.post( "admin_post.php", { id: id, update: "update" })
  .done(function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
 });

</script>
```

**admin_post.php**

```
<?php
$updateQuery = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT * FROM `PRODUCT` WHERE `p_id`={$_POST['id']}");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($updateQuery)) {
    $p_name = $row['p_name'];
    echo $p_name;
};
```

Comment: Your method returns an empty value as in " Data Loaded: "

Comment: This means your php on admin_post.php page isn't returning what's expected --  Change the entire contents of `admin_post.php` to `<?= 'test' ?>` and see if the string `test` gets returned :-)

Comment: Replace all the php in the external file with that? I just did and now nothing happens.

Comment: Well that was something. helpfulness = -1

Comment: I can only lead a horse to water ..  Look at your console and do basic troubleshooting!  instead of `alert(data);`  use `console.log(data);`